# Can restcomm support multiplayer video

Tags: restcomm

Hi，i used restcomm to develop app,when I  see it's code i found

```
private void startCall(SignalingParameters signalingParameters)
 {
  RCLogger.i(TAG, "startCall");
  callStartedTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

  // Start room connection.
  logAndToast("Preparing call");

  // we don't have room functionality to notify us when ready; instead, we start connecting right now
  this.onConnectedToRoom(signalingParameters);
}
```

so i want to know if the restcomm-android-sdk not support multiplayer video now ??

Answer (score 2):

Pengwang, depends what you refer to by multi-peer video. As of now, Restcomm Android SDK supports P2P audio/video, which means that two people can have video-chat. But it doesn't support more than two yet.

Hope this helps,
Antonis Tsakiridis